# Java Script add value of variable to object property?

Tags: javascript

I'm new here and to JavaScript.  I have an assignment that asks "create a new property in the foodInfo object plus the value of the toppings variable, and set the ne property's value to to value of the current element in the toppingBoxes array."

Here is the code I have that is not working, I have tried multiple things but cant get it to print out the toppings on the page:

```
for (var i = 0; i < toppingBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (toppingBoxes[i].checked) {
        toppings = toppings + 1;
        foodInfo.topping[toppings] = toppingBoxes[i].value;
    }       
}
```

Here is the code the assignment gave me to print it, so this code is correct, but the code above is what I need help with:

```
foodSummary.innerHTML += "<ul>";
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if (foodInfo["topping" + i]) {
        foodSummary.innerHTML += "<li>" + foodInfo["topping" + i] + "</li>";
    }
}
foodSummary.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

I know the code stops running when it hits the line "foodInfo.topping[toppings] = toppingBoxes[i].value;" so I know that is wrong.  I am having trouble with the instructions I mentioned above...any help to get this working?  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var toppings = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < toppingBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (toppingBoxes[i].checked) {
        toppings = toppings + 1;
        foodInfo['toppings' + toppings] = toppingBoxes[i].value;
    }       
}
```

Comment: You sir/madam are a genius!  Thank you so much for helping this noob!  The book I am working from sucks at teaching what we can and cannot do, then asks us to do vague things and it's just a guessing game from there.  I really appreciate the help!